# Importing data using Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, core-data, swift3, magicalrecord

I try to import data from JSON array like this :

```
let json = JSON(value)
let data: [[String: Any]] = self.transformJson(json)
MagicalRecord.saveInBackground({ (localContext) in
    User.mr_import(from: data, in: localContext)
})
```

The problem is the mr_import swift method call  `MR_importFromObject:inContext:` instead of `MR_importFromArray:inContext:`

Here's the exception :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_SwiftValue 0x6080000c9e60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109ae4d4b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010cf4a21e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000109ae4c99 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x000000010cb247c5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:]
>   + 226     4   Foundation                          0x000000010ca5060b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 283     5   Foundation                          0x000000010ca53eec -[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 467  6 
>   Foundation                          0x000000010ca503e8
>   -[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 448   7   MagicalRecord                       0x000000010a968ce8 -[NSObject(MagicalRecord_DataImport)
>   MR_lookupKeyForAttribute:] + 232  8   MagicalRecord
>
>   0x000000010a968efe -[NSObject(MagicalRecord_DataImport)
>   MR_valueForAttribute:] + 62   9   MagicalRecord
>
>   0x000000010a95b7c7 __75+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord_DataImport)
>   MR_importFromObject:inContext:]_block_invoke + 135    10  CoreData
>
>   0x000000010d4519a7
>   developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 199  11 
>   CoreData                            0x000000010d45185f
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 255  12  MagicalRecord                       0x000000010a95b5db
>   +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord_DataImport) MR_importFromObject:inContext:] + 331     13  Kairos
>
>   0x0000000108e057ce
>   _TFFZFV6Kairos8DataSync10fetchUsersFFOS_13StatusRequestT_T_U_FGV9Alamofire12DataResponseP__T_U_FCSo22NSManagedObjectContextT_
>   + 158     14  Kairos                              0x0000000108dc9ecc _TTRXFo_oCSo22NSManagedObjectContext__XFdCb_dS_** + 60   15  MagicalRecord                       0x000000010a953671
>   __73+[MagicalRecord(ActionsDeprecated) saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion:]_block_invoke + 129  16 
>   CoreData                            0x000000010d4519a7
>   developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 199  17 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e9740cd
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e951e17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236   19 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e952b4b
>   _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073     20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e95302b _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 683    21 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e955385
>   _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720  22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e955059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123   23 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ed23712
>   _pthread_wqthread + 1299  24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ed231ed start_wqthread + 13 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating
>   with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Somebody who knows MagicalRecord and uses it might be able to answer the question off the bat, but otherwise, providing a sample project with the issue in action might be the easiest way to get an answer since not everybody might be familiar with all the different components involved in the issue. If you can upload a sample project somewhere and provide a link, do let me know and I'll take a look.

Comment: The most significant information of the crash log is *-[NSObject(MagicalRecord_DataImport) MR_valueForAttribute:]* and  *this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id*